# How to conditional format a range of cells without creating a rule for each?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a column of values that i want to conditional format if it is a text and not equal to "---". My question is how would i apply just one rule to each of the column cells without the rule referencing back to where the rule applies D360?

Here's my formula for conditional format:

```
=AND(ISTEXT($D$360),$D$360<>"---") 'formats to red text
```

If i put this formula as a rule for each D360:D390, if my D360 is text, the whole range D360:D390 will be red, i only want the cell the rule is on to turn red.

Comment: Remove the `$` in front of both `360`

Comment: @ScottCraner If I put my formula in each cell i want conditional formatted on, and change the D360 to whatever the cell is on, it works fine, my question, is there a way to specify only 1 rule that covers each cell so that when each cell is a text, it will be red and not all at once if D360 happens to be a text.

Comment: Just the one formula, applied to your whole range.  The cell reference in the formula should be the first row in the applied to range.  Try it, and it will do what you want. one rule for the whole range.  The `$` locks the row number.  By making the Reference `$D360` the row is relative.

Comment: that did it, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Highlight your cells that you want formatting, add the formula for the first row but make sure you remove the absolute cell references:
Remove the $ sign from the row number of the test.